# Get rows that contain less than 4 digits only

Tags: mysql, regex

I need to fetch the rows that contain less than 4 consecutive digits. I tried using this :

```
select mycolumn where mycolumn REGEXP '[0-9]{1,3}'
```

but this still returned rows such as 
`"Test Text 1234-1234"`
I need to return these only:

```
Test 12
Test 234 Text
Test /2 Text
text 123 text 1234 text
```

Comment: What happens if you add word boundaries to your RegExp?

Comment: @BenM That did it.  '[[:<:]][0-9]{1,2}[[:>:]]' Thanks.

Comment: @user3340627 You probably mean `'[[:<:]][0-9]{1,3}[[:>:]]'` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af95e/3/0

Comment: Word boundaries will not work if you want to match things like `123test` and `test123`. Since there are no lookaheads in MySQL I think you need to split in several expressions for that.

Comment: @lad2025 you're right i meant {1,3}

Comment: @bolav I see, but I don't have such cases in my data. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @BenM and @lad2025, the correct answer is:

```
'[[:<:]][0-9]{1,3}[[:>:]]'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af95e/3/0

Comment: @Strawberry Yes but i would need to wait for two days to be able to do so